# How to display loading image before data loading into kendo mvc ui grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am working on asp.net mvc 3. I am trying to display list of records using kendo mvc ui grid. and i have set editable mode to popup so the processing could be done on server. I want to display loading image before data is loading into the grid that means during paging,refreshing etc. I have used the grid like

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("GrdXXX")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:1000px;" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.xxx).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.yyy).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.zzz).Width(80);
        columns.Bound(p => p.State).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Phone).Width(70);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("Edit Details"); command.Destroy().HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "return DeleteConfirm();" }); }).Width(120);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Zip Code"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).Window(m => m.Title("Edit Zipcode").Draggable().Resizable()))
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Server()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.RecNo))
                .Update("Update", "ghj")
                .Create("Create", "ghj")
                .Destroy("Delete", "ghj")
    )
)
```

I have tried using ajax jquery calls but it doesnt work for me. so please guide me.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I solved explicitly adding loading effect to Kendo grid by extending jQuery. It uses the native Kendo styling.

```
$.extend($.fn, {
        busy: function (c) {
            b = $(this);
            var d = b.find(".k-loading-mask");
            c ? d.length || (d = $("<div class='k-loading-mask'><span class='k-loading-text'>Loading...</span><div class='k-loading-image'/><div class='k-loading-color'/></div>").width(b.outerWidth()).height(b.outerHeight()).prependTo(b)) : d && d.remove()
        }        
    });
```

And then use it as

```
$("#grid").busy(true); // change to false to hide loading effect
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution as recommended by Telerik:

```
// show loading indicator
kendo.ui.progress($element, true);

// hide loading indicator
kendo.ui.progress($element, false);

// $element is a jQuery object. The element must have a position:relative style applied
```

Ref. http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-manually-show-and-hide-loading-or-spinning-image#Y_apWF417kKpicdUz0NUHg

Answer (score 0):

The grid will display a loading image automatically if it were configured for ajax binding. Your grid is configured for server binding which relies on regular HTTP GET requests (no Ajax). A loading image would be immediately removed once the browser starts making the HTTP GET request.

Comment: i need to show popup window for editing records or add new records. so i should use server() method. Is there any way to put loading effect explicitly during paging,loading etc.

Comment: No. And I think I said that in my reply.